# Про git. Почему, если удалить коммит, созданный merge, история из сливаемой ветки остаётся

Tags: git

Есть ветка master. В мастере создали коммит 1.

После чего создали и переключились на ветку develop.
В ней создали коммиты 2, 3, 4. Смотрим git log - там коммиты с 1 по 4.

Переключились на ветку master. Смотрим git log - там коммит 1.
Мы же в другой ветке.

Теперь делаем git merge develop. Создался коммит 5 из 2 веток.
В git log уже 5 коммитов.

Потом понимаем, что рано ветки слили и делаем `git reset --hard HEAD~1` и последний коммит исчезает.
Смотрим git log, а там коммиты 1, 2, 3, 4.
Да, но коммита, соединяющего ветки уже нет.

Почему коммиты из ветки develop отображаются в master?
По идее у них есть общий предок, но на данный момент нет коммита, соединяющего эти две ветки.

Как сделать "unmerge" чтобы коммиты из сливаемой ветки, не отображались в главной ветке?

Comment: *Создался коммит 5 из 2 веток* — что-то вы не договорили. из предыдущего описания следует, что никакого нового коммита при слиянии не должно было быть создано. либо вы добавляли коммиты в ветку master после создания ветки develop, либо явно (или неявно) указали делать слияние без fastforward.

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей. Желательно вывод `git log --graph --oneline` сразу после мержа

Comment: Так у вас скорее происходят две вещи: 1) как таковое слияние является fast-forward, 2) merge-commit всегда создаётся как сказано скорее всего в конфигурации. Когда вы "сливаете" всё так и просиходит. То есть нет никакой ошибки здесь. Вам надо запомнить заранее где был указатель HEAD перед merge. Потом соответственно на него делать сброс, а не на одно изменение назад от головы.

Answer (score 0):

У коммита 5 два предка: 1 и 4

Судя по описанию того, что вы получили в итоге, была ошибка или в порядке слияния, или в  синтаксисе reset'а

В данном случае достаточно еще раз сделать `git reset`, вручную указав коммит 1